# sudo apt install in github action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, apt

In one of the project I work on, I use `graphviz` for visualization and have test code for this functionality.

But to test the code `graphviz` must be installed. I setup CI as the github action.
But I couldn't manage to install `graphviz` as the github action.

We have the following yml

```yaml
name: test
on: push
  
jobs:
  test_coverage:
    name: Test Software
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # See: https://github.com/actions/checkout
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Graphviz
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -y install graphviz
```

But it fails with

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

I am using Github Enterprise, if this means anything.
How can I fix such an issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first which users is executing that command:

```yaml
run: |
  id -a
  sudo apt-get -y install graphviz
```

Said user is probably not added to the sudoers.
Yet, the [GitHub Actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges) mentions:

> The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless sudo. When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more privileges than the current user, you can use `sudo` without needing to provide a password.
> For more information, see the "[Sudo Manual.](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.27/sudo.man/)"

Check if this works better with:

```yaml
runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
# or
runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
```

---

For the [OP dragon-and-dracula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289302/dragon-and-dracula), in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711745/sudo-apt-install-in-github-action/74712855#comment131940772_74712855):

> I ended up using my own container that got the `graphviz` preinstalled.
> I think the main reason for the error was because something about GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: I've tried that but gave me the same error. I ended up using my own container that got the `graphviz` pre-installed. I think the main reason for the error was because something about Github Enterprise....

Comment: @dragon_and_dracula Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.